# cannot retrieve selected data based on session query sql

Tags: session, authentication, fetch, display

Hello to all PHP Masters...I hope I'm not troubling anyone...I'm sorry if my question is wrong or not suitable for this section. My english is not that good. I've tried to solve this problem for a few days and tried searching for answers but could not find any solution that can solve my problem. Firstly, I apologise, because honestly, I'm a newbie in PHP and I'm really really a newbie and need your guidance.

I already have a login page (login.php). When the user login, they will be directed to user page (useracc-test.php).It suppose to display their personal data based on their username and password session but it shows error (
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 42

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 51
Hello, ().).

I have no problems on DB connection issues, because I can display ALL users data in the "useracc-test.php". The only problem is, I cannot display SELECTED data based on user's login session. I want the user's to retrieve thier own data instead of everyones data.

Below is the user page "useracc-test.php". This is the page after user login succeeds and suppose to display their own personal data. Need your help.. Tq again.. Linda May.

```
    <?php

//useracc-test.php

/**
 * Start the session.
 */
session_start();

 /**
 * Include our MySQL connection.
 */
// require 'lib/password.php';
require 'connect-test.php';

/*
THIS ONE WORKS FINE..BUT IT DISPLAY ALL ROWS...BUT THE ONE BELOW "$_SESSION['user_id']"
DISPLAYS ERROR

$sql = "SELECT name, telno, username FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "name: " . $row["name"]. " - telno: " . $row["telno"]. " username" . $row["username"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

*/



//THIS ONE BELOW DOES NOT WORK FINE..DISPLAY 2 ERRORS
/*Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 49
Hello, (). */
//Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 42

//$sql = "SELECT name, username FROM users WHERE id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ;
$sql = "SELECT name, username FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else{

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "Hello, " . $row['name'] . " (" . $row['username'] . ").";
}



?>
```

---

#### login.php

```
<?php

//login.php

/**
 * Start the session.
 */
session_start();



/**
 * Include password_compat library.
 */
require 'lib/password.php';

/**
 * Include our MySQL connection.
 */
require 'connect.php';



//define variables and define to null.
$usernameError = $passwordError = "";


//If the POST var "login" exists (our submit button), then we can
//assume that the user has submitted the login form.
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    //Retrieve the field values from our login form.
    $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
    $passwordAttempt = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

    //Retrieve the user account information for the given username.
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    //Bind value.
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);

    //Execute.
    $stmt->execute();

    //Fetch row.
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //If $row is FALSE.
    if($user === false){
        //Could not find a user with that username!
        //PS: You might want to handle this error in a more user-friendly manner!
         $usernameError = "Invalid username. Username is required";
          $passwordError = "Invalid password. Password is required";
    } else{
        //User account found. Check to see if the given password matches the
        //password hash that we stored in our users table.

        //Compare the passwords.
        $validPassword = password_verify($passwordAttempt, $user['password']);

        //If $validPassword is TRUE, the login has been successful.
        if($validPassword){

            //Provide the user with a login session.
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();

            //Redirect to our protected page, which we called useracc.php
            header('Location: useracc-test.php');
            exit;

        } else{
            //$validPassword was FALSE. Passwords do not match.
           $passwordError = "Invalid password. Password is required";
        }
    }

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>


         <style> 

.error { 
 color: #CB1313; 
  font-family:arial; 
  font-size: 10pt; }


    </style>



    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">

            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input class="input" name="username" maxlength="50" input type="text" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"   > <span class="error">* <?php echo $usernameError; ?></span> <br>

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input class="input" name="password" maxlength="16" input type="password" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"  > <span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordError; ?></span><br>

            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to paste my login page...below is my login.php.

Comment: it seems I cannot insert more than 15 characters for my login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same while loop you are using in the working file, like:

```
if (!$result) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} else{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Hello, " . $row['name'] . " (" . $row['username'] . ").";
    }
}
```

The undefined index error is caused by a missing $_SESSION value (`username` is not defined in $_SESSION).

Either use the already defined `$_SESSION['user_id']` in your query OR define `$_SESSION['username']` properly then it should work.

---

#### Additional Notes

You will need to store a cookie or something rather than just use $_SESSION, $_SESSION is only going to be valid right up until you redirect the user to the useracc-test.php.

You can see that it works if instead of redirecting you just include the useracc-test.php like:

```
        //Include the page instead of redirect
        include('useracc-test.php');
        exit;
```

Comment: :-)   tq for the reply sebastianForsberg.. I tried your code.. but I got error.."Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 43"

Comment: Ill post my login.php in the answers section.. because in comment section.. characters too long.

Comment: Ok, so line 43 contains this: `$_SESSION['username']`, meaning that `username` was not set in $_SESSION global variable. You need to set that value if that is how you want to query for the user in the database. You commented out the `$_SESSION['user_id']` query which should be set already...

Comment: wowwwwwwww..tq so much Master sebastianForsberg.. I change to  'include('useracc-test.php');' on my login page.. NOw I can retreive user's personal data.... Then I changed  from $_SESSION['username'] to $_POST['username']..and the error on line 43 works.......wow..tq sooo much.... but what I'm puzzled is.. the URL above.. after I login.. i still shows login.php instead of userracc-test.php.... is that normal??

Comment: I'm really not sure how to set $_SESSION global variable.. I've never tried it before..can u show me how and where i should put it.. but at the moment everything seems fine already.. but Im just puzzled about the URL http when I entered data.. it never moves to useracc-test.php.. only remains at login.php.

Comment: **typo error above:  "and the error on line 43 works " to "and the error on line 43 dissapears"

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on basic session/cookie handling in PHP, something like [this](http://devzone.zend.com/16/php-101-part-10-a-session-in-the-cookie-jar/) Or just search around for setting cookies with PHP. That is something that others have already explained in great detail on the Internet.

Comment: Ok Master sebastianForsberg..tq for being generous.. I really appreciate it.. tq so much ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//login.php

/**
 * Start the session.
 */
session_start();



/**
 * Include password_compat library.
 */
require 'lib/password.php';

/**
 * Include our MySQL connection.
 */
require 'connect.php';



//define variables and define to null.
$usernameError = $passwordError = "";


//If the POST var "login" exists (our submit button), then we can
//assume that the user has submitted the login form.
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    //Retrieve the field values from our login form.
    $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
    $passwordAttempt = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

    //Retrieve the user account information for the given username.
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    //Bind value.
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);

    //Execute.
    $stmt->execute();

    //Fetch row.
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //If $row is FALSE.
    if($user === false){
        //Could not find a user with that username!
        //PS: You might want to handle this error in a more user-friendly manner!
         $usernameError = "Invalid username. Username is required";
          $passwordError = "Invalid password. Password is required";
    } else{
        //User account found. Check to see if the given password matches the
        //password hash that we stored in our users table.

        //Compare the passwords.
        $validPassword = password_verify($passwordAttempt, $user['password']);

        //If $validPassword is TRUE, the login has been successful.
        if($validPassword){

            //Provide the user with a login session.
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();

            //Redirect to our protected page, which we called useracc.php
            header('Location: useracc-test.php');
            exit;

        } else{
            //$validPassword was FALSE. Passwords do not match.
           $passwordError = "Invalid password. Password is required";
        }
    }

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>


         <style> 

.error { 
 color: #CB1313; 
  font-family:arial; 
  font-size: 10pt; }


    </style>



    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">

            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input class="input" name="username" maxlength="50" input type="text" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"   > <span class="error">* <?php echo $usernameError; ?></span> <br>

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input class="input" name="password" maxlength="16" input type="password" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"  > <span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordError; ?></span><br>

            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: I think I got error maybe the loginpage relates to the error on useracc-test.php. I think so... somewhere.. I'm just not sure.. I already tried twist and turn and tried many attempts.. but could not solve the problem..

Comment: I'm not sure if this type of error is very high end or very complicated error..because i search the internet.. could not find suitable solution.

Comment: I can retrieve and display ALL users data.. but I cannot retrieve and display user's PERSONAL data..